# How Do I Order Results By Field Using ExactTarget API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I am making a call to the ExactTarget SOAP Service for Subscriber objects.  How can I order the results by Last Name, for example?  Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any way through the API to order the results returned for `Subscriber` object, or any other object. I believe they are returned in the order added.

When you get back the payload, you would need to sort in the order you want using your development language.

Comment: Does one +1 an answer they're totally unhappy with but is 'correct'?

Comment: The right answer doesn't mean you have to like it, unfortunately.

Comment: Then here's a +1! :)

Comment: I feel your pain.